# How to multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to multiply an array of arrays by a certain number. That it, multiply each value of each array by the same constant. I was trying to do it this way:

```
>>> a = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> b = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> c = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> 0.1 * [a,b,c]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Is there a smarter 'Numpier' way to do it rather than creating a for loop?

Comment: What result do you want here? How can it make sense to multiply a list by one tenth?

Comment: You right, I had to explain better - I try to multiply each value in the array of arrays by the same constant, such that each cell will get the value 0.1 in this example.

Comment: Integer array multiplication does not have the same semantics in Python and in Numpy. You just need to transform all your arrays in Numpy arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying python lists by an integer gives you a multiple of the list.

```
>>> a = [1]
>>> a * 3
[1,1,1]
```

The *Numpier* way of what you are trying to do would be to actually use numpy. Then you can multiply the values inside an *array* by whatever you want:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> a * 0.1
array([[ 0.1,  0.1],
   [ 0.1,  0.1]])
```